# Keras apply different Dense layer to each timestep

Tags: python, keras

I have training data in the shape of `(-1, 10)` and I want to apply a different Dense layer to each timestep. Currently, I tried to achieve this by reshaping input to `(-1, 20, 1)` and then using a `TimeDistributed(Dense(10))` layer on top. However, that appears to apply the same Dense layer to each timestep, so timesteps share the weights. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a dense layer of a vector 200-wide which is created by copying the input 20 times, like so:

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *

model = Sequential()
model.add(RepeatVector(20, input_shape=(10,)))
model.add(Reshape((200,)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile('sgd', 'mse')
model.summary()
```